# Using JSTL causes deferredExpression error on change

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jstl

I recently removed all scriptlets on my project as advised by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).  But now, if I try and make a change to one of my views, I get a deferredExpression error.  To get rid of the error, I simply have to terminate, then restart the project.

What is going on here? Is eclipse not able to compile jstl on the fly? Is there something I can change so I don't have to redeploy every time I make a change?

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.release(ForEachSupport.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool.release(TagHandlerPool.java:166)
    at org.apache.jsp.l.profile_jsp._jspDestroy(profile_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.destroy(HttpJspBase.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.destroy(JspServletWrapper.java:428)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:141)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.appspot.MySite.Controller.FacebookLogin.doFilter(FacebookLogin.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: What is the full exception? This seems to be alone the message part of a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError` exception. If so, please edit your question to include the full exception and stacktrace.

Comment: What's the source of the error. Can you show the code that's causing this error?

Comment: @Vivin: abstract classpath-related errors are hardly caused by code. Posting code won't help solving this kind of errors. Regardless, according to the stacktrace OP is using `<c:forEach>` in `profile.jsp` file.

Comment: @BalusC I should have taken more time to read the stack trace. I thought it was caused by him doing something strange in his jsp. Thanks for educating me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression
> at apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.release(ForEachSupport.java:212)

Your classpath is polluted with different JSTL implementation versions. This particular exception means that you've both the `jstl-1.2.jar` file of JSTL 1.2 and the `standard.jar` file of JSTL 1.1 or 1.0 in the classpath. This field is introduced in JSTL 1.2 and the `ForEachSupport` class is present in the both JAR files. Apparently at some point the one of `standard.jar` is been loaded and used while still having the JSTL 1.2 API in JVM memory.

The solution is to **remove** the `standard.jar`. You don't need it for JSTL 1.2 at all.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (to learn about what JARs you need)

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you actually need to **remove** the `jstl-1.2.jar` as well, because the Servlet 2.5 compatible version of GAE/Jetty apparently already ships with JSTL 1.1 out the box. This was conflicting with JSTL 1.2. in your webapp.

Comment: I can't find standard.jar in war/WEB-INF/lib or in any other jar locations.  Where should I be looking for this file?  Are there any other files that could be causing a similar conflict?

Comment: Perhaps in GAE/Jetty's own lib? Or even in JRE/lib(/ext)? Or maybe in flavor of an all-containing `j2ee.jar` or `javaee.jar` which you hijacked from other container like Glassfish in order to circumvent compilation errors in your project instead of compiling it against GAE/Jetty's own libs?

Comment: Thinking once again about this, doesn't GAE/Jetty actually already ship with JSTL out the box? I recall some questions related to this... In that case you'd need to remove `jstl-1.2.jar` instead and rely on the JSTL 1.1 libs of GAE/Jetty itself. Or maybe downgrade to JSTL 1.1 compatible libs. What servlet version is your `web.xml` declared to by the way? And what servlet version does GAE/Jetty currently support as max?

Comment: I removed jstl-1.2.jar and now everything works fine, thank you.  Is there anything I will be missing using 1.1 vs 1.2?

Comment: My xml is set to 1.0 and my web app version is 2.5

Comment: Ah, glad that it works. I'll update the answer. As to the changes, there's nothing changed with regard to core functionality. It was only a bit retrofitted to take benefit of the new EL 2.1 API. Also, the two JARs were merged into a single JAR.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have two versions of JSTL (javax.servlet:jstl:). Remove the older version and make sure you update the version everywhere you were using the older one, and you should be good.