# random error. "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression"

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:275)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

**I am getting this error randomly**.
I am getting this error any time and if i restart my tomcat it goes away!!!!
I am not getting this error in my local system but i am getting this error when i run my project on web-server.

Comment: JspServlet.java:275 : what is written on this line

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7837576/1285418) might help

Comment: Du you use it in a multi-thread environment? Concurrent access of more than one thread can randomly provoke errors.

Comment: @Pau Kiat Wee I am having standard.jar , standard-1.1.2.jar , jstl-1.1.2.jar , jstl-1.2.jar , jstl.jar in my lib folder. which jar should i remove ???

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you have multiple different version of JSTL libraries in classpath.

You can remove:

- standard.jar
- standard-1.1.2.jar
- jstl-1.1.2.jar
- jstl.jar

Comment: Sorry, no: containers are not guaranteed to provide JSTL. If you are using Tomcat and want JSTL, you'll have to provide it in your webapp's WEB-INF/lib directory. Be sure not to have JSTL libraries in Tomcat's (server) lib/ directory as well.

Comment: I would like to add that in my case I get that error as I have jstl-1.1.2 and jstl.jar, both together does not work well also seems that jstl.jar contains some standard.jar stuff