# How to increase a value from populated field in struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, urllib2

Hi Good Morning to All!

I have one problem. I am developing a web application by using struts 2. I am doing paginating. i.e. 10 records per page. Here i need two links one is "Previous" and another one is "Next". Here i have populated the bean values like this two as ,

For Previous link as,

```
<c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
 <tr>
   <s:url id="previous" action="retrieve">
    <s:param name="condopurchaselistbean.currentPage">${currentPage-1}</s:param>
   </s:url>
   <td><s:a href="%{previous}" >Previous</s:a></td>
 </tr>
</c:if>
```

For Next link as,

```
<c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">
 <tr>
   <s:url id="next" action="retrieve">
     <s:param name="condopurchaselistbean.currentPage">${currentPage+1}</s:param>
   </s:url>
    <td><s:a href="%{next}" >Next</s:a></td>
  </tr>
</c:if>
```

But its not working. Below is the exception i am getting :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:268)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:157)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.visionraices.interceptors.MyLoggingInterceptor.intercept(MyLoggingInterceptor.java:64)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

I dont know. What is my mistakes. 
Anybody can help me?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at tablesorter jquery plugin.
Or you can use limit and offset at your backend databse query for each click of next or previous.(You are making a call to database each time you click on next or previous.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now i have used JQuery Table plugin. All my problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple libraries of JSTL on your classpath (webapp + app server for example).

For this guy with your same error it worked: [random error. "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781701/random-error-javax-servlet-servletexception-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-defer)

---

Not related to your problem, but why are you using `JSTL IF`s instead of `Struts2 IF`s ??

You could easily change `<c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">` to `<s:if test="%{currentPage < noOfPages}">` or even `<s:if test="currentPage < noOfPages">`, and it would be better. Actually, with S2 you don't need JSTL anymore.