# Is it necessary to restart the server each time before running , when using JSTL?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, hotdeploy

I have been trying to use JSTL to write my JSP pages .However I noticed something,whenever I make any changes to my page , try to save and run the page without restarting the page throws an error as below.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.release(ForEachSupport.java:178)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool.release(TagHandlerPool.java:165)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.WatchEvent_jsp._jspDestroy(WatchEvent_jsp.java:42)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.destroy(HttpJspBase.java:60)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.destroy(JspServletWrapper.java:478)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:166)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: this means you are partially compiling your code see this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686753/nosuchfielderror-java

Comment: can you tell which all jars you have on your classpath ?

Comment: Check this:[Using JSTL causes deferredExpression error on change][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837576/using-jstl-causes-deferredexpression-error-on-change

Comment: jstl-1.1.2.jar,jstl-1.2.jar