# Random error started after quick successive releases of the app "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jstl

Random error started after quick successive releases of the app
"Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.release(ForEachSupport.java:178)"

I uploaded a new version of the app a few times in a few minutes as i was playing around with facebook OG tags and debugging it as it needed to be on the live site for FB to see it (hence many quick changes).
and, the app just stopped working and starting throwing servlet JSTL errors for Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError.

I have read that it is when you have 2 versions of the JSTL Jar but i havnt changed that, i just think google is getting screwey and not cleaning the working dirs on new upload.
(e.g. [Using JSTL causes deferredExpression error on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837576/using-jstl-causes-deferredexpression-error-on-change))

I have tried incrementing the version number in the hope of it creating a fresh instance but it doesn't seem too. Has anyone come across this before and got any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Isnt this the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837576/using-jstl-causes-deferredexpression-error-on-change

Comment: Yes, it is similar in that it is happening @farrellmr, but my main worry was that i have been using GAE (Google App Engine) for years and it has never been an issue, and then *bam*, it blows up.